# What does this mean when vscode remotely debugs machine learning code? Is it stuck? How to solve the problem besides quitting?

Tags: debugging, machine-learning, visual-studio-code, computer-vision, pytorch

**When vscode remotely debugs the machine learning code, it will get stuck. I will choose to disconnect, I want to know why it is stuck**

Comment: most likely you have an error in your script, start with the simples script possible and add bit by bit until the error happens

Answer (score 0):

I is not only about vscode all are coding languages debug to machine language to work your code in your laptop or smartphone or desktop. You need to start your remote debugger after configure remote debugging to configure the firewall. When configuration is complete the remote debugger window appears. Then you can use the server name and port number shown to set the remote connection.

vscode remote development allows you to use container, remote machine or windows subsystem.